# LaTeX remove subsection from TOC

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I use the following code in LaTeX to set the level of contents in the table of contents:

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}\newcommand{\restoretoc}\addtocontents{toc}
{\protect\vspace*{2.5em}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}}
```

The ouput is the following:

[image]

The counter disappears but subsubtitle and page number are still there. How to remove all the counter, title and page number in the table of contents for the subsubsection?

Answer (score 2):

A first simple suggestion:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First first}
\section{First second}
\subsection*{First second first}
%\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\subsection{First second second}
\end{document}
```

This way, the "starred" `\subsection*` (or section or chapter) does not appear in the table of contents.

Furthermore, uncommenting the line `\setcounter{subsection}{1}` (and editing the digit `1` in it) you can play with the following subsections number as you prefer. **Compile twice to test this**, because table of contents file requires it to update the output pdf or dvi file.

What I wrote about `subsection`s applies to `subsubsection`s too if counter `secnumdepth` is set to `3` or more.

Comment: You can upvote clicking the arrow up and accept clicking the tick sign under it! Also the first upvote is ok for getting to not-unanswered-anymore. Thank you!